# Rails 4.0.0, RSpec-rails 3.0.2, capybara 2.4.2 visit undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I am using the mentioned configuration and created feature in folder **spec/features**
But I am still getting visit undefined method error. Here is the code.

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'view list of movies' do
  it 'shows movie list' do
     visit 'http://localhost:3000/movies'
     expect(page).to have_text('2 movies')
  end
end
```

This results in following error.

```
  undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups:view list of movies:
```

Any suggestions appreciated.
I created this question as I tried all the possible solutions mentioned in those 4 questions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your `rails_helper.rb` :

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'
```

In your feature add:

```
require 'rails_helper'

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked in mac osx. But it is not working in windows 7. Also I did not include include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!